Unable to detect mouse movement with pynput mouse listener when run as a service
I am trying to create a windows service using python that monitors mouse movement and keyboard presses. The code works fine when ran in the console however when I modified it to turn it into a service, its not detecting the mouse movement. I asked ChatGPT for it and it said that windows services run in non-interactive environment.
So is there anyway to achieve my requirements. Btw, I am using pywin32 to install it as a service and it successfully runs and does everything else as expected.
here's the code:
mouse_listener = None
def monitor_mouse():
    # write_log("s0", log_path)
    # global timer
    global mouse_listener
    # mouse_listener = mouse.Listener()
    mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_move=reset_timer, on_click=reset_timer, on_scroll=reset_timer)

    mouse_listener.start()
    mouse_listener.join()


Take a look at the updated code.
